# Copy a file instead of move in php

Tags: php

I am sending an image from my app to a php file then moving it into a directory - i want to duplicate the image so i can save it in a second place, but once i use

> move_uploaded_file

it is gone from the temp and cant be used a second time. Is there an alternative to just copy it? here is my code

```
    if (isset($_FILES["media_file"]) && $_FILES["media_file"]["size"]>0){
        $filename=$_FILES["media_file"]["name"];
        //$fullfilepath="form_media/".$form_id."-".$filename;
        $fullfilepath="room_media/".$form_id."-".$form->name."-".time().$filename;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media_file"]["tmp_name"],$fullfilepath);

$ref = $form_id;
$namee = 'savedimages/' . $ref . '.png';

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media_file"]["tmp_name"],$namee);

        $emUrl = "http".
        "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=='80'?"":(":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'])).$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $codeUrl=dirname($emUrl)."/".$fullfilepath;
        $url=$codeUrl;
        $formimage->room_id=$form_id;
        $formimage->image_url=$url;
        R::store($formimage);
    }
```

I save the file to room media first using :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media_file"]["tmp_name"],$fullfilepath);
```

But then i cant save it to "savedimages", only if i comment the above line out can i get the image to save in "savedimages".

Thanks

Comment: copy it from where you moved it?

Comment: Tried `copy()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: Copy() is the same as move_uploaded_files

Comment: @mistermartin I want to save it from the temp into both "savedimages" and "room_media"

Comment: It certainly isn't the same function :-P One moves the file from one location to another (description from [manual of `move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php): "***Moves** an uploaded file to a new location*") while the other copies it (description from [manual of `copy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php): "***Copies** file*").

Comment: move_uploaded_file is just for uploading. Once you've uploaded it to your preferred destination, use `copy` on that file to your second directory.

Comment: @GazSmith `copy($fullfilepath, $secondLocation);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should be

```
 copy($_FILES["media_file"]["tmp_name"],$fullfilepath);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["media_file"]["tmp_name"],$namee);
```

Hope this helps

Just make sure you use copy first

Comment: You can copy after as well, just have to use the target-destination of `move_uploaded_file()` instead of the `$_FILES`

Comment: thanks for that mate, worked perfect